# Pandas DataFrame has multiple rows instead of columns

Tags: python, pandas

this might be a very simply question, even after quite some time I could not manage what I want.

I have a pandas Dataframe from which I would like to add a couple of cols from one row to a new DataFrame. In this more values shall be added and then this DataFrame shall be appended to another one.

Somehow my "df_row" is always displayed as one column. When I then append this to my df_result it has also only one column instead of 6.
Where is the error?

Thx

```
#Create empty df
df_result = pandas.DataFrame(columns= ["filename, class, x, y, lbl, pred, c_pred"])

# Make new df from an existing one (not shown)
# This deliveres a frame with 6 Rows instead of 6 columns
idx = 1 #Normally used in a loop
df_row = pandas.DataFrame([df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 0:1].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 1:2].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 2:3].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 3:4].values, label, pred.item(), correct_prediction], columns= ["filename, class, x, y, lbl, pred, c_pred"])

# Has also only one column
df_result = df_result.append(df_row)
```

Comment: Add some example data and what your expected output is.

Comment: You shoud show the existing one so we can understand what you are trying to do. At least few rows, if it is big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seems to be with these lines:

```
   df_result = pandas.DataFrame(columns= ["filename, class, x, y, lbl, pred, c_pred"])
   df_row = pandas.DataFrame([df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 0:1].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 1:2].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 2:3].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 3:4].values, label, pred.item(), correct_prediction], columns= ["filename, class, x, y, lbl, pred, c_pred"])
```

you are giving all column names as one string which makes only one column. try this

```
  df_result = pandas.DataFrame(columns= ["filename", "class", "x", "y", "lbl", "pred", "c_pred"])
  df_row = pandas.DataFrame([df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 0:1].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 1:2].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 2:3].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 3:4].values, label, pred.item(), correct_prediction], columns= ["filename", "class", "x", "y", "lbl", "pred", "c_pred"])
```

Comment: Thx, now there is an error: Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (7, 7)

Comment: that means at some point in your code you are still making that mistake mentioned above.. check it out yourself first. if there's still problem show me rest of code

Comment: Solved it! I added another pair of brackets:   df_row = pandas.DataFrame([[df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 0:1].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 1:2].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 2:3].values, df.iloc[idx:idx+1, 3:4].values, label, pred.item(), correct_prediction]], columns= ["filename", "class", "x", "y", "lbl", "pred", "c_pred"])

Comment: yup. thats it. happy codiing